# PIsarenko Harmonic Decomposition method for PSD estimation

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density

i would like to present  steps for estimation Power Spectrum density using Pisarneko Harmonic  Decomposition
[image]

i would like to present code for  step 1 part

```
function [vmin,sigma]=phd(x,p)

% the Pisarenko Harmonic decomposition
x=x(:);
R=Covar(x,p+1);
[v,d]=eig(R);
sigma=min(diag(d));
index=find(diag(d)==sigma);
vmin=v(:,index);
end
```

now let us  consider following time series

```
fs=100;
ts=1/fs;
t=0:ts:2.93;
x=10*sin(2*pi*10*t)+15*cos(2*pi*10.5*t)+14*sin(2*pi*10.19*t)+3*randn(size(t));
```

PSD using music method can be estimated  as follow

```
pmusic(x,6);
```

[image]

how can i  got the same result using pisrenko harmonic decomposition? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $v_{min}$, the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue, compute the function $\hat{P}_{PHD}(e^{j\omega})$.

The vector $e$ [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisarenko_harmonic_decomposition) $e = [1 \quad e^{j\omega} \quad e^{2j\omega} \ldots e^{pj\omega}]$

Make a plot of $\hat{P}_{PHD}(e^{j\omega})$ and measure the $p=3$ peaks to find the frequencies.

Comment: but how to compute?  i need this one,  what i know is that i need to compute z transform  for calculate eigenfillter and find  roots, but how can i do it in matlab

Comment: You don't need to compute the Z transform, the equation for $\hat{P}_{PHD} $is all you need